# How to make a dataframe containing complex numbers from dataframes with real numbers in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, complex-numbers

In python, I have a dataframe with 2 columns of real numbers. I want to make complex number and use those two columns as real and imaginary parts of my new set of data. I have tried `complex(df['wspd'].astype(float),df['wdir'].astype(float))` but I still get this error:

```
cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

How can I make it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `complex` can handle only scalars. You can convert the second column to imaginary multiplying by `1j`, then sum:

```
df['wspd'] + df['wdir'] * 1j
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'wspd':[10.23,2.4,30.6], 'wdir':[2.3,7.8,4]})
df['com'] = df['wspd'] + df['wdir'] * 1j
print (df)
    wspd  wdir           com
0  10.23   2.3  (10.23+2.3j)
1   2.40   7.8    (2.4+7.8j)
2  30.60   4.0     (30.6+4j)
```

Comment: Btw [extending pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/extending.html) might be useful here as well

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to create a new dataframe `df2` from `df` in this way:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([complex(i.wspd, i.wdir) for i in df.iloc], index=df.index)
```

The .iloc (int based indexing) and .loc (label based indexing) object attributes of Dataframes are iterable and therefore can be used in this way.

The alternative to the python native complex function is to use numpy.complex, I'm not sure which is faster, probably the numpy function as pandas inherits data types from numpy.